# Can't read beyond first iteration in "for...of" loop / iteration is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have an array, questionsArray, and i need to do something in every question inside that array. The first iteration works, but beyond that it says that it cannot read property x of null. Why is that?
-This is the code that loops through the array:

```
var insertion = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    for(const question of questionsArray){
                        await db.query('INSERT INTO `ml-questions-data` (`text`, `status`, `question_id`, `answer_text`, `answer_status`, `answer_date`, `item_id`, `seller_id`, `created`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);',
                         [question.text, question.status, question.id, question.answer.text, question.answer.status, question.answer.date_created, question.item_id, question.seller_id, question.date_created], (erro)=>{
                            if(erro){
                                reject(erro)
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log('array iteration! db insertion')
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    resolve()
                });
```

-And this is the questionsArray data:

```
[
    {
        "date_created": "2019-09-30T03:18:08.000-04:00",
        "item_id": "MLB1329418290",
        "seller_id": 158369990,
        "status": "ANSWERED",
        "text": "olá, gostaria de entender como funciona isso?",
        "id": 6553335409,
        "deleted_from_listing": false,
        "hold": false,
        "answer": {
            "text": "pois bem, vamos adicionar um texto de resposta no json",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "date_created": "2019-09-30T03:24:52.120-04:00"
        },
        "from": {
            "id": 444188609,
            "answered_questions": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "date_created": "2019-09-30T03:22:21.000-04:00",
        "item_id": "MLB1329418290",
        "seller_id": 158369990,
        "status": "BANNED",
        "text": "<p style=\"display: inline-block;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,'sans-serif';font-size:13px;line-height:17px;background: url('http://static.mlstatic.com/org-img/ch/ui/0.10.7/assets/icons.png') no-repeat;border-radius: 3px;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;margin: 0 0 5px;padding: 8px 10px 8px 34px;text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);background-color: #FCF8CB;background-position: -225px -101px;border-color: #E4E2B8;\">Tivemos que excluir esta pergunta porque não está de acordo com as nossas <a href=\"https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/ajuda/politicas-para-cadastramento-de-produtos_1002\">Políticas para Cadastramento de Anúncios</a>.</p>",
        "id": 6553335807,
        "deleted_from_listing": false,
        "hold": false,
        "answer": null,
        "from": {
            "id": 444188609,
            "answered_questions": 2
        }
    },

    the array goes on.....
]
```

And this is the error node prompts:

```
C:\ServidorMaster\Alura\ProjetosNODE\project2>node server
server rodando na porta 3010
Conexão com banco de dados mySQL estabelecida
**(node:9360) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
    at Promise (C:\ServidorMaster\Alura\ProjetosNODE\project2\src\app\modelos\DAOs\mercado-livre\ml-DAO.js:205:88)**
(node:9360) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9360) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
**array iteration! db insertion**
```

So it says in cannot read the property, but the first iteration, an object, was inserted successfuly in my DB. Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: is your problem still persist after check for null?

Comment: No, its fixed now. Thank you so much for helping me out. Its my first "big" project and im working day and night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"answer" is null in the second element of your array, so you cannot access question.answer.text.  (In the first element of the array, answer is a map with an element named "text").

You will need to deal with the case where answer is null in the input array for all of the parts of the insert that try to access its members.

Comment: Thank you so much <3 i dont know how i missed that. I think i need to get some sleep hahaha. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Make check

```
question.answer?question.answer.text : ""
```

So basically this is a null check on **answer object**. So if answer is not null then it only it will execute **question.answer.text**

else it will give/assign "" empty value

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: If you use this solution, you will also run into the problem that question.answer is referenced multiple times (question.answer.status is right after question.answer.text) so you need to address all of the places where question.answer is referenced.